# Address is not imported while restoring 12-word backup

Tags: wallet-recovery, seed, passphrase

I tried to restore my 12-word backup with `Copay` and `Electrum` but non of them listed the addresses my money is stored in. What to do in this case?

[image]

Comment: What software did you use to generate the 12 word mnemonic? It's likely that that wallet used a different derivation path than what Copay or Electrum use by default. Also, Electurm uses a different mnemonic format than what other wallets typically use. If you did not specify BIP 39 and your mnemonic came from a BIP 39 wallet, you will get wrong addresses.

Comment: Used Copay to create backup.